# Unable to create regex pattern

Tags: python

I have a string

```
81.5r3
```

I need to create a regex pattern, So that I should get a exact list as mentioned below

```
['81.5', 'r', '3']
```

The pattern should be float, char, int

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to be more specific about the patterns of data you want to match. Otherwise this question is too broad. As currently written, someone could answer with `(81\.5)(r)(3)`

Comment: @Nick I have mentioned how I need the output. What else should I mention?

Comment: float, char and int?

Comment: "the patterns of data you want to match". Are they all a floating point number, a letter, and a digit? Or is the pattern different?

Comment: @python_user Yes

Comment: Try something like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) for quick experimentation?

Comment: So a "char" is any single character including letters a-z, A-Z, digits, punctuation etc? Or is it just a lower case letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 re.split(r"([a-z])", '81.5r3')
```

You can use `re.split` using a capture group to get what you want.

The output would be `['81.5', 'r', '3']`

Comment: You can mark this as accepted if it helped you

Answer (score 2):

Try something like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) for quick experimentation?

For a "float, char, int" sequence, it'll be something like:

```
(-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)(.)(-?[0-9]+)
```

You can refine it if you want to do things like forbid leading/trailing zeros:

```
(-?[1-9][0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*[1-9])?)(.)(-?[1-9][0-9]*)
```

You may also need to refine it if you need to support exponential notation (1.2e3) or NaN/Inf values for the float part.

Answer (score 2):

```
(\d+[.]\d)([a-z])(\d)
```

I made a simple regex. I think that's enough for you to upgrade it, good luck, and happy new year.

Please check

https://regex101.com/r/kFYzag/5

Please use [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kFYzag/4/) to try your idea.

Image result
[image: Result]